# Moving from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012-express

I am moving an app from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012 Express, and all is well but several stored procedures are saying I have a syntax error. I have looked online and have not found an answer - are there types of syntax that are supported in SQL Server 2008 (Standard) but not in SQL Server 2012 Express?

Comment: None that I can think of. Maybe you can show an example and the ACTUAL error message. Some smart folks here, but very few mind-readers.

Comment: Sorry, I know it is vague but the errors are all over the place.  Some syntax, some saying an object does not exist, etc.  I have not worked with MS products before but I thought it could be something like going from perl4 to perl5, or php 4 to php5, where certain things break and there is a conversion guide out there.  I don't know that to be the case and I have not found one but I suspected something like that could be the answer.  I will add some actual error messages.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess there is one possibility, if in 2008 you were using 2000 compatibility mode, and your stored procedures had old-style outer joins:

```
SELECT o.name, c.name
FROM sys.objects AS o, sys.columns AS c
WHERE o.[object_id] *= c.[object_id];
```

This syntax works in SQL Server 2000, but has been deprecated since then. In 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2 you could shoe-horn it in if you use 80 compatibility mode. As of SQL Server 2012, you can no longer use 80 compat mode, so the above code would fail with:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near '*='.

In 2008, you would get this error message instead:

> Msg 4147, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> The query uses non-ANSI outer join
>   operators (`"*=" or "=*"`). To run this query without modification,
>   please set the compatibility level for current database to 80, using
>   the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE. It is strongly
>   recommended to rewrite the query using ANSI outer join operators (LEFT
>   OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN). In the future versions of SQL Server,
>   non-ANSI join operators will not be supported even in
>   backward-compatibility modes.

But if you alter the database as suggested in the error message, it would work:

```
ALTER DATABASE foo SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 80;
```

This seems like a stretch. But without some real information it's about the only guess I have.

Comment: The "Incorrect syntax near '*='" was one of the messages I got.  It was a version 2000 compatible database before.  I had never seen that kind of syntax.  What is the best way to go about converting or learning about what needs to be converted?

Comment: @zortacon: The error message says it all: `It is strongly recommended to rewrite the query using ANSI outer join operators (LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN).`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) of deprecated features in SQL Server 2012-- take a look at the T-SQL section(s) in particular.  You could also use SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools), create an offline copy of your DB and then set the version targeting to SQL Server 2012 - the output would show show many of the syntax incompatibilities between versions.  I wrote a blog about SSDT that might be helpful [here](http://lynnlangit.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/sql-server-2012sql-server-data-tools/).